# Resultado de função JAVA Android

Tags: java, android, funções

Tenho uma pergunta bem simples para quem ja entende de Java mas esta me quebrando a cabeça.
Sendo direto, tenho minha MainActivity e um layout com dois EditText's e um botão, e uma Classe SistemaHttp.
 Queria que quando clicasse no botão, os valores dos campos fossem para a SistemaHttp, verificasse o usuario e senha e mostrasse o retorno na MainActivity.
O problema é que como sou inicante em Java não consigo fazer isso, mas já tenho um base da funçao (quase) funcionando:

MainActivity:

```
    txt_usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
    txt_senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.senha);
    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String user = txt_usuario.getText().toString();
            String pssw = txt_senha.getText().toString();

            SistemaHttp sHttp = new SistemaHttp(getBaseContext());

            sHttp.retornaUsuario(user, pssw);

        }
    });
```

SistemaHttp:

```
public String retornaUsuario(String user, String pssw)
{
    String u = "Teste";
    String s = "123";
    String resp = "";

    if (user.equals(u) && pssw.equals(s))
    {
        resp = "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        resp = "ERRO";
    }

    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    main.retornoLogin(resp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro aparente  é apenas na classe SistemaHttp:

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
main.retornoLogin(resp);
```

Não é necessário instancia a classe MainActivity para retornar, 
quem fará isto é o próprio método, pois ele retorna uma String, certo?

```
public String retornaUsuario(String user, String pass)
```

Então quando você realizar a chamada no click, ele irá passar o resultado! 
Para isso deve alterar o método para a seguinte forma:

```
public String retornaUsuario(String user, String pssw)
{
    String u = "Teste";
    String s = "123";
    String resp = "";

    if (user.equals(u) && pssw.equals(s))
    {
        resp = "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        resp = "ERRO";
    }
// passamos a quem solicitou o retorno !
  return resp;
}
```

A sua chamada deve estar assim :

```
SistemaHttp sHttp = new SistemaHttp(getBaseContext());
String valido = sHttp.retornaUsuario(user, psst);

if(“OK”.equals(vaido)){
//esta OK
}else{
// nao esta OK
}
```

Comment: Caraca velho, valeu mesmo, voce explicando é tão simples mas como sou iniciante nessa linguagem tava mais perdido que cego e tiroteio kk